# H2 Database issue : Column interpretation with CSVREAD and convert function

Tags: csv, h2

I am currently using h2 version 1.4.196. I have a CSV file as follows,

```
Status,message,code
1,hello,13
2,world,14
3,ciao,26
```

Following query works as expected & returns proper Status values.

```
select "Status" from  CSVREAD('myfile.csv', 
'Status,message,code', null) ;
```

Following query produces an exception. It seems like the literal string "Status" is being passed to convert instead of the values returned by the
execution of the query. I am not sure if my understanding of convert is 
correct. Please help me with fixing this query to return the desired result. Thanks in advance.

```
select convert("Status", int) from  CSVREAD('myfile.csv', 'Status,message,code', null) ;

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Status" 
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) 
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:940)
```

----------------------Detailed Exception------------------------------

```
select convert("Status", int) from  CSVREAD('myfile.csv', 
'Status,message,code', null) ;
Data conversion error converting "Status"; SQL statement:
select convert("Status", int) from  CSVREAD('myfile.csv', 
'Status,message,code', null) [22018-196] 22018/22018 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "Status"; SQL statement:
select convert("Status", int) from  CSVREAD('myfile.csv', 
'Status,message,code', null) [22018-196] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:996) 
    at org.h2.expression.Function.getSimpleValue(Function.java:945) 
    at org.h2.expression.Function.getValueWithArgs(Function.java:1196) 
    at org.h2.expression.Function.getValue(Function.java:591) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select$LazyResultQueryFlat.fetchNextRow(Select.java:1459) 
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.hasNext(LazyResult.java:79) 
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.next(LazyResult.java:59) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:519) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:625) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:114) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:371) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:333) 
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:113) 
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:186) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:164) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.getResult(WebApp.java:1380) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:1053) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1015) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1002) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:164) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:89) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Status" 
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) 
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:940) 
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using it you're defining the columns and reading all the rows from the csv, so you're getting the first row with `Status` as well. Then you try to convert the string `Status` to an integer which obviously results in exeption.

Instead you shouldn't define the columns but let h2 get them from the first row of the csv:

```
select convert(status,int) from CSVREAD('myfile.csv');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. Your suggestion worked perfectly.